Converting Multiple FITS files into one dataset?
I am doing a project involving data from LASCO C2 on the SOHO spacecraft. I tried to download the data from the SOHO science archive and it comes out as multiple FITS files. Is there a way to convert multiple FITS files into one big dataset chart? I ultimately want to use the dataset in Google Colab for my project.

Space Exploration SE might be a better fit for this, or Astronomy SE.

I think Space Exploration more than Astronomy - this is definitely related at least tangentially related to space exploration, I think less so astronomy.

Why on earth would SpaceEx be suited for this question about file conversions? FITS is at least an astronomy-centric file format, so questions about it ought to be on topic there (not being a user there, I have no idea).

AFAIK, each file contains header information about the image described in the remaining file. Combining them into one file probably isn't possible.
